# Strange issue with SBT, println, and scala console application

Tags: scala, io, console-application, sbt

When I run my scala code (I'm using SBT), the prompt is displayed after I enter some text as shown here:

```
C:\... > sbt run
[info] Loading project definition [...]
[info] Set current project to [...]
Running com[...]
test
>>





exit
>> >> >> >> >> >> [success] Total time[...]
```

It seems like it's stacking up the *print()* statements and only displaying them when it runs a different command.

If I use *println()* it works as it should (except that I don't want a newline)

The code:

```
...
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    var endSession:Boolean = false
    var cmd = ""
    def acceptInput:Any = {
      print(">> ")
      cmd = Console.readLine
      if (cmd != "exit") {
        if (cmd != "") runCommand(cmd)
        acceptInput
      }
    }

    acceptInput
  }
...
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Try `Console.out.flush` after each print.  It's probably a buffering issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Output from `print` (and `println`) can be buffered.  Scala sends output through `java.io.PrintStream`, which suggests that it will only auto-flush on newline, and then only if you ask.  It might be OS dependent, though, since my `print` appears immediately.

If you add `Console.out.flush` after each `print`, you'll empty out the buffer to the screen (on any OS).